# Related Post w/ Thumbs error in WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use the below PHP code to bring in related posts at the end of the `single.php` main post page.

**EG:** *Homepage > click a post > Post page (single.php) > Underneath the content is 3 related posts with thumbnails.*

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<!-- Related Stories -->

<div class="postCategory" style="">Related Stories<br />


        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div style="width:100%;" align="center">
        <div style="width:495px;" align="center">    

            <?php foreach( $Featuredposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <?php //$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;  //print("$do_not_duplicate"); ?>
            <?php if($featured_image=get_post_meta($post->ID, "featured_image", true)) { ?>  

            <div style="display:block; width:150px; margin:0 15px 0 0; float:left" align="center">
                <a class="oborder" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $featured_image; ?>" heigh="124" width="143" border="0" /></a>            
                <span style="display:inline;"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" style="display:inline;"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
            </div>    

            <?php }?>               
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
       </div>


 <!-- End Pull in Related Stories -->
```

**Here's the error I'm getting:**

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /data/24/1/0/139/1815302/user/1967139/htdocs/RIF/wp-content/themes/crown_readitforward2012/single.php on line 280
```

*Line 280 =*      `<div style="width:495px;" align="center">` ??

*(When I removed that - I get error at line 281)*

*Line 281=*   `<?php foreach( $Featuredposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print_r your $Featuredposts to make sure it has data.

```
print_r($Featuredposts);
```